# Adding search and time stamp filter to Elastic Search Nest client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to search and filter data using c# Nest client 
Below is the query written using  Javascript-Elastic search and similar client i am trying to write in c# but its not working as expected

Javascript Elastic Search client :

```
    var from_ms = from.getTime();
    var to_ms = to.getTime();
    var query = 'temp:' + Temp + ' AND url:"type=' + value + '"';
    client.search({
    type: 'Type',
    size: 5000,
    q: query,
    body: {
        sort: [
        {
            "@timestamp": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
        ],
        filter: {
            "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                    "from": from_ms,
                    "to": to_ms
                }
            }
            //"range": { "@timestamp": { "from": 1444118389, "to": 1444120189 }} 
        }
    }

}).
```

C# Elastic Search code i tried but its not working as expected 
I am not getting how can i add the query in c# as i have in JS and how to filter data using time stamp

```
    class ElasticearchQuery
{
    public class REstt
    {
        public string test{ get; set; }

        public string url { get; set; }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var connection = new X509CertificateHttpConnection();
            var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("https://www.yy.com"));
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool, connection);
            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
            REstt person = new REstt();
            QueryContainer query = new TermQuery()
            {
                Field = "temp",
                Value = "value"
            };


            var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
            {
                From = 0,
                Size = 5000,
                Query = query
            };
            var searchResults = client.Search<REstt>(searchRequest);
            var temp = searchResults.Hits;


            Console.WriteLine(temp);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Have you seen [date range query usage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/date-range-query-usage.html#date-range-query-usage) in NEST docs?

Comment: @Rob : Yes, I saw i believe it will help me to filter using time stamp but i am getting confused how can i append  var query = 'temp:' + Temp + ' AND url:"type=' + value + '"'; to the search request and include the body: { with the search request to filter using timestamp. I am new to Nest so don't have much idea how can i form the query and search parameters.